# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index during column creation in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Tried to put all the count's value into the data frame and wanted to save as csv file but the error (ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index during column) came even the length is the same.

```
import cv2
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

################################################################
path = "C:\pfm\seg/"

ids = os.listdir(path)
#print(ids)

counts_list = []
df =pd.DataFrame()

for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(ids), total=len(ids)):

    
    df = pd.read_excel(path+id_)
    print(path+id_)

    df.head(1)

    plt.hist(df['Area'],bins=15)
    counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(df['Area'],bins=15)
    print(counts)
    

    #sns.distplot(df['Area'], kde=True, bins=100, color='red')
    #sns.pairplot(df.loc[:,['Area']])
    
    counts_list.append(counts)

    
    df['counts'] = counts_list

    
    df.to_csv('C:\pfm\seg/counts.csv')

    plt.xlabel('Pearlite Area')
    plt.title(ids[n]+'Pearlite Area distriburion')
    
    plt.savefig(ids[n]+'.jpg')

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better provide sample data. I take a modified example from https://datatofish.com/plot-histogram-python/.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = [1,1,2,3,3,5,7,8,9,10]

plt.style.use('ggplot')
counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(x, bins=10)
# counts is now array([2., 1., 2., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

You get an array back from the counts and add it to a nested list 'counts_list'.

```
counts_list = []
for i in range(10):
    counts_list.append(counts)
```

Generate some data:

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame([x]*10)
```

If you need need one column per counts item you split the sub-elements into columns again before putting them in the df.

```
df_with0countsColumns = pd.DataFrame([counts]*10, columns=[a for a in range(min(x), max(x)+1)])
df_no0countsColumns = pd.DataFrame([[int(a) for a in counts if a in x]]*10, columns=[a for a in range(min(x), max(x)+1) if a in x])
df = pd.concat([df_x.add_suffix('_x'), df_no0countsColumns.add_prefix('countsOf_')], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   0_x  1_x  2_x  3_x  4_x  ...  counts_5  counts_7  counts_8  counts_9  counts_10
0    1    1    2    3    3  ...       1.0       1.0       1.0       1.0        1.0
1    1    1    2    3    3  ...       1.0       1.0       1.0       1.0        1.0
2    1    1    2    3    3  ...       1.0       1.0       1.0       1.0        1.0
...
```

Or if you need just one column with all counts as a string:

```
df = df_x.add_suffix('_x')
df['counts'] = [','.join(str(int(y)) for y in x) for x in counts_list]
```

Result:

```
   0_x  1_x  2_x  3_x  4_x  5_x  6_x  7_x  8_x  9_x               counts
0    1    1    2    3    3    5    7    8    9   10  2,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
1    1    1    2    3    3    5    7    8    9   10  2,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
2    1    1    2    3    3    5    7    8    9   10  2,1,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
```